# How to redirect to subdirectory after session timeout in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a few very similar asp.net mvc applications running on single IIS website. Each of those applications has it's own sub-directory, i.e. www.contoso.com/app1, www.contoso.com/app2 etc.

The problem I'm facing is that when the user session times-out, it's redirected to www.contoso.com main address, not /app1 or /app2 application addresses.

What are the possible solutions to that problem?

Comment: You need to change line 1342

Comment: what redirections do you have put in place in the configuration file?  Are you sharing the authentication cookie across sites?

Comment: are all your controllers locked down with [authorize] attribute?